# Specified Cast is invalid from SQL row to a GUID

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have tried everything online and tried converting it to a string then Guid but I keep getting this error.

```
                if ((DateTime)objRow["ExamDate"] > dDateGranted)
                {
                    dDateGranted = (DateTime)objRow["ExamDate"];
                }
                if (objRow["ExamId"].ToString().ToLower() != SPIExamID.ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet("new_beenprocessed");
                    var examID = objRow["ExamResultId"];
                    oExamResult = (New_ExamResult)objService.Retrieve("new_examresult", (Guid)examID, cols);
                    oExamResult.New_BeenProcessed = true;
                    objService.Update(oExamResult);
                }
```

When I am debugging its value is "87F5E8FB-8105-E611-9E7C-00155DF30E9B" so I know that it is a GUID but the CrmOrganizationServiceContext will not recognize it as a GUID. If I try new Guid(examID) it says that it cannot convert an object to a byte.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var examID = new Guid(objRow["ExamResultId"].ToString());
```